# Anybody know why using a custom shape-drawable will remove your stateListAnimation on a button?

Tags: android, android-drawable, objectanimator, shapedrawable

I'm using custom shape drawables all the time. But theoretically it should work with stateListAnimators perfectly right?

Also I think this is also related as to why using a custom shape-drawable removes the shadows added to the view when you have an elevation attribute.

Comment: "I'm using custom shape drawables all the time" are you extending `ShapeDrawable` thus making custom shape drawables?

Comment: no I mean in the xml. I don't extend ShapeDrawable